# How do I configure OWIN to handle Facebook, but only after logging in via a proprietary system?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, owin

I already have an application that uses a proprietary authentication system that authenticates the user.

I want this web app to connect to the user's Facebook, Gmail, and Twitter accounts.

- Is it possible to use OWIN to handle the OAuth responses, but never, ever modify or use the current authentication mechanism.

I want to prevent a security issue where a Facebook, Gmail or Twitter account is used as a back-door authentication to the system.

Comment: So you want your users to have login credentials within your web app, and you just want your app to connect to your users' social network accounts?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want to connect your app to Facebook, Google or Twitter, without integrating your app's login with these social network sites. If that is the case, I do not think you need OWIN for this.

Facebook has a JS SDK which allows you to check if your visitor's [FB login status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus). Your app will still need to be registered on FB and your user will still need to authorise your app to access user's profile info.

Google's [Sign-in for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) which allows you to check the user's login status (or what it calls the [user's session state](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state).

It does not look like Twitter allows you to check a user's login status. There's a [similar SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555338/is-there-a-legitimate-way-to-check-the-twitter-login-status-of-a-user-visiting-m).